# Blender 2.8 Boolean changes texture scale

Tags: modifiers, scale, texture-coordinates

I want to add a cavity for a window using a boolean modifier.

[image: Wall with boolean cube]

I used a cube as the boolean object, but the scale of the texture is different on the faces created by the boolean cube.

[image: Scale of texture is different]

Is there a way to get the material to have the same properties as the rest of the object without applying the boolean modifier?

Thank you.

Comment: Probably your mesh or the uv map is scaled itself.

Comment: Thanks, I can fix this by scaling the uv map